# How to delete all local branches except master and develop in one command without aliases?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

When working on projects with Git Flow or similar workflow where more than one stable branch exists I create a lot of feature branches (`feature/do-something-1`, `hotfix/fix-bug-1`, etc.).

Sometimes I need to clear the list of local branches because it is literally impossible to manage them with dozens of rudimentary branches. I usually delete them one at a time by copying and pasting the branch names into the `git branch -d` command. But it takes so long that it's easier to delete the entire repository and clone again.

**I want to delete all of them except `master` and `develop` in one command** (without writing additional shell script/aliases), but all solutions I've found on the internet only allow you to delete everything except one branch (`master`, for example). This is not an appropriate solution. Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Comment: Why could you not adjust what you have found for deleting all but one branch to deleting all but two branches?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's do it in steps so we can break down the command and understand what it does:

```
 git branch | grep -v " master$" | grep -v " develop$" | xargs git branch -D
```

*Note: You cannot delete a branch that is currently checked out.*

**Step by step**:

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/branch_del_test (master)
$ git branch
  develop
* master
  test
  test2

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/branch_del_test (master)
$ git branch | grep -v " master$"
  develop
  test
  test2

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/branch_del_test (master)
$ git branch | grep -v " master$" | grep -v " develop$"
  test
  test2

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/branch_del_test (master)
$ git branch | grep -v " master$" | grep -v " develop$" | xargs git branch -D
Deleted branch test2 (was 7767978). <-- only the output of the last xargs run is shown

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/branch_del_test (master)
$ git branch
  develop
* master
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Can you please briefly explain the command in the answer? it will be helpful if we want to modify this command for other uses. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a step-by-step walk through of the command.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simpler variant of same answer:

```
git branch -D $(git branch | grep -v -e "master$" -e "develop$")
```