# Git - Delete local branches except 'master' and current branch

Tags: windows, git, powershell, command

How I can delete all my local branches in VS 2017, except 'master' and current branch? without 'grep' command.
I use with PowerShell in windows.

For some branches I did

`git branch -D (git branch --list 2.68*).trim()`
and it works.

I want improve it.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete all local branches except master and develop in one command without aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116879/how-to-delete-all-local-branches-except-master-and-develop-in-one-command-withou)

Comment: No, Because i can't use with 'grep' command.

Comment: PowerShell has plenty of regex capabilities built-in

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell's `Where-Object` command to filter the output from `git branch --list`:

```
$allLocalBranches = git branch --list 
$branchesToDelete = $allLocalBranches |Where-Object {
    # the current branch is prefixed with `*`, so we can filter it out
    # by requiring branch names that start with whitespace
    # and then we also filter out the `master` branch
    $_ -match '^\s' -and $_.Trim() -ne 'master'
}

$branchesToDelete |ForEach-Object {
    # now we can go ahead and delete the remaining branches
    git branch -D $_.Trim()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can i do something easier?

Comment: @RinaBarak I don't know. What makes you think of this as not-easy?